# On *nix is there a way to trigger a process at a future date & time?

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking to allow a user to enter a date and time to send out a mass email through PHP, although I'm thinking it might be best to use a *nix command to trigger the PHP process. I'm wondering if there is a way on *nix to do this without adding a cronjob to run every 15 minutes to check if there is a mass email to be sent. It's not that this is an intensive process, but it'd just be much prettier with a cronjob to add and manage. I thinking this would be somewhat similar to a Windows scheduled task that has an end date and is set to delete if it's not scheduled again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for the [at](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=a/at) command.

> at [options] time [date]
>
> Execute commands at a specified time
>   and optional date. The commands are
>   read from standard input or from a
>   file. (See also batch.) End input with
>   EOF. time can be formed either as a
>   numeric hour (with optional minutes
>   and modifiers) or as a keyword. It can
>   contain an optional date, formed as a
>   month and date, a day of the week, or
>   a special keyword (today or tomorrow).
>   An increment can also be specified.
>
> The at command can always be issued by
>   a privileged user. Other users must be
>   listed in the file /etc/at.allow if it
>   exists; otherwise, they must not be
>   listed in /etc/at.deny. If neither
>   file exists, only a privileged user
>   can issue the command.
>
> In typical usage, you run at and input
>   commands that you want executed at a
>   particular time, followed by EOF.
>
> $ at 1:00 am tomorrow at>
>   ./total_up > output at> mail joe <
>   output at>  Entered by pressing
>   Ctrl-D job 1 at 2003-03-19 01:00
>
> The two commands could also be placed
>   in a file and submitted as follows:
>
> $ at 1:00 am tomorrow <
>   scriptfile

Comment: Also make yourself familiar with the sytem and users "crontab" files.

Comment: "at" has loads of options.  I find  echo "<the command>" | at 2300  
Does what I want 99% of the time.  (any 24 hr time will do of course!)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`at`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).